# Postgresql weird outcome after joining on dates with interval of 1 month

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a table like this:

```
     Date  user_id
========= =======
 1/2/2018    1
 3/4/2018    2
 2/2/2018    1
4/17/2018    2
etc.
```

The table indicates the date a user accessed a website and user_id is the user id.

I wanted to check whether the user logged in a month and in the previous month.
I wrote the next query:

```sql
SELECT a.user_id, to_char(a.date::date, 'YYYY-MM') as a, to_char(b.date::date, 'YYYY-MM') as b
FROM mytable a
         left JOIN mytable b
         on to_char(a.date::date, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(b.date::date - INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM')
         and a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1
```

However, when I run this query table a shows the previous month and table b is the next month like:

```
   a.Date    b.Date  user_id
========= ========== ======
 1/2/2018  2/2/2018   1
 3/4/2018  4/17/2018  2
```

I expected this to be the other way around, why is the output like this?
I guess it can be also done with partition?

Edit:
By the other way around what I meant is that the output I got a.Date should have the data in b.Date and otherwise.

Edit 2:
Solved and shared my solution.

Comment: What output you are expecting?

Comment: The other way around the output I got meaning a.Date should have the data in b.Date and otherwise, I will edit the question.

Comment: (1) What if a user has several rows per month, what would the result look like? (2) What if they have records this month but not last month (or the other way around)?

Comment: :@GMB  1) I do not care about a few records, that why I grouped by (maybe I am wrong with the way I did it). 2) I should get null that's why I did a left join

Comment: Looks like you solved it yourself finally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to join this way:

```sql
on to_char(a.date::date , 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(b.date::date+ INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM')
```

Which mean the current month for example is 10 and the previous is 9 +1 and then
it will print the desired result.